# new Array(5).toString() returning four commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods

- to understand the below code snippet I looked at this link.
- But still I am not able to figure it out why its printing four commas in the console.
- since I am creating array of five items
- can you tell me how its working.

```or-tag-here
new Array(5).toString();
",,,,"
```

Comment: it's the space between elements.

Comment: its like a,b,c,d,e if you see here there are 5 elements but only 4 commas

Comment: @NinaScholz hey but there are totally five arrays right so it should have five commas right?

Comment: Your code is the equivalent of doing `[,,,,].toString()`.

Comment: @zizi Refer to my answer below. Think of how you declare an array of items; you only have commas _between_ two items, with no extra comma after the last item.

Comment: with 5 elements, you have 4 separators.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon btw [trailing commas are ignored since ES5](http://2ality.com/2013/07/trailing-commas.html), so it will need 5 commas, but that will probably confuse OP even more

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon—not quite, `[,,,,].length` is 4. ;-)

Comment: @slai—the article is a little misleading. "Trailing commas" were always allowed, but early IE had a bug that treated them as syntax errors. Further, IE also didn't treat elisions correctly so `[,,]` created an array of length 3 when it should have been 2. ECMA-262 was modified more-or–less to accommodate IE's buggy behaviour. So `[0,1,]` always should have created an array of length 2, not because trailing commas are ignored, but because the final elision doesn't increment the length. But now it's explicit in EMCA-262. And `[1,2,,]` creates an array of length 3 (as it always should have). :-)

Comment: @Slai—oh, on reading ECMAScript ed 3 and comparing to the latest edition, the spec wasn't actually changed in any meaningful way, there were just some words added to clarify that trailing elisions are ignored (as they always should have been), reinforcing that it's the elision (the non–existent value after the comma) that's ignored, not the comma itself. :-)

Comment: when I searched I couldnt find out. I tried and posted. Can you tell me how to remove the negative marks :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine what it would look like with values in each of the array indexes.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].join(); // Returns 1,2,3,4,5
```

Now if you remove the numbers, you're just left with the commas in the middle.

```
new Array(5).join(); // Returns ,,,, because the values are blank.
```

Comment: when I searched I couldnt find out. I tried and posted. Can you tell me how to remove the negative marks :(

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` method iterates throw all elements in the `Array` push them into string and push `,` betweeen them.

As you defined empty Array with 5 elements, when you apply `toString` it convert it to five "empty" strings with 4 "," between them

Comment: It doesn't exactly iterate the elements as (in the OP's case) there aren't any, it iterates from 0 to *length*. ;-)

Comment: when I searched I couldnt find out. I tried and posted. Can you tell me how to remove the negative marks :(

Answer (score 1):

`new Array(5)`returns a [sparse array](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html) or an array with 5 empty spaces inside. The only thing that this does is to set the `length` property of the array object to the specified argument (5 in this case).

```js
console.log(new Array(5)) // browser console --> [empty × 5]
```

So naturally if you attempt to print its contents it would show you that you have 5 empty spaces separated by `,`

```js
console.log(new Array(5).toString()) // ,,,, <-- 5 empty ',' separated elements
```

Comment: when I searched I couldnt find out. I tried and posted. Can you tell me how to remove the negative marks :(

Comment: "negative marks" ? You mean the downvote `-1` on your question?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see, `someArray.toString()` will return what is inside the array but without `[` and `]`.

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5])
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].toString())
```

So, if you have noting in the array element, it will return empty string and only print the comma. (`Array(5)` is the same as `[,,,,,]`)

```js
console.log([,,,,])
console.log([,,,,].toString())
```

`Array(5)` will return an array only with the property `length: 5`. Wich will make it's elements `undefined`.

If you want to make it something else then `undefined` you can use `.fill`

```js
console.log(Array(5))
console.log(Array(5).fill(""))
console.log(Array(5).fill("anything"))
```

Comment: hey but why is your second code snippet returning undefined :(

Comment: @zizi Because even though `console.log(...)` outputs what's in the parentheses to the console, the function `console.log` itself doesn't return a value. The first code snippet does the same thing.

Comment: Now you're going to have to explain why `[,,,,,]` only generates an array of length 5 not 6. ;-)

Comment: when I searched I couldnt find out. I tried and posted. Can you tell me how to remove the negative marks :(